# Make link in lower z-index level clickable

Tags: html, css, z-index

I would like to make an anchor that is in a lower z-index clickable, here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mjooh3gv/

Setting the z-index only for the anchor (that's different from the partent div) does not work.

```
.underlay a {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

Comment: Why not display the link on the highest z-indexed div?
http://jsfiddle.net/mjooh3gv/2/

Answer (score 2):

What's the point in layering the two DIVs on top of each other in the first place?

If you want to position elements at the outer edges of a container, you can use several methods:

- `postion: relative` on the container and `postition: absolute` on the children, or
- `float: left` and `float: right` on the children (with clearing the container), or
- using `display: inline-block` and `width: 50%` on the children, or
- a layout `<table>` with two columns (Yeah, I know. Sue me.), or
- using `display: table-row` on the container and `display: table-cell` on the children, or
- `display: flex`, see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

The latter would work like this:

```css
.container {
    border: 5px inset red;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
}
.overlay {
    margin-right: auto;
}
.underlay {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">
        <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="underlay">
        <a href="#2">Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a pretty messed up design-situation, that forces me to layer the divs :/ But thanks for your answer, I'll use one of your techniques, if nothing comes up with the z-index-clickable-thing!

Comment: To me it seems that you can decide about the width of the elements, so you have the power to make them non-overlapping.